# Algebraic treatment of Feynman potential wells?

Tags: abstract-algebra, mathematical-physics

This question refers to the discussion here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084883/chomsky-feynman-thom

I will try the divide-and-conquer strategy to try to make some progress in the problem dealt with in the above-mentioned link.

My question is then a very straightforward one. Let us consider a double potential well such as the first figure in the following link (it is crucial that the depth of both wells be the same) 
http://inspirehep.net/record/862281/plots

We assume an object, particle, whatever, to be in one of those two stable positions. We want to get to a state where the particle ends up in the other stable position and stays there. From a geometrical or topological point of view it is quite obvious how we get there. The question is:
How would you formulate the whole thing algebraically, be it with abstract algebra, with category theory, whatever?

Comment: I should maybe specify that also formalization of the additional possibility in which a tunnel between both wells makes it possible for the particle to move from one stable position to another would be welcome from my part. But the emphasis should be on the normal case.

Comment: I have found this paper on the net:http://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/physics/issues/fiz-04-28-3/fiz-28-3-3-0312-1.pdf     The thing is, I would need a solution which is independent of measures, lacking numbers, based just on logic, letters and the like, if you know what I mean.